# Matplotlib symlog linear region

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having some difficulties plotting lines which go to zero on a logarithmic (or `symlog`) axis. Consider this simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

pl.close('all')

z = np.linspace(0,1,20)
x = np.ones_like(z)
x[0] = 0

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(131)
pl.plot(x, z, '-x')
pl.xlim(-0.1,1.1)

pl.subplot(132)
pl.plot(x, z, '-x')
pl.yscale('log')
pl.xlim(-0.1,1.1)

pl.subplot(133)
pl.plot(x, z, '-x')
pl.yscale('symlog', linthresy=1e-2)
pl.xlim(-0.1,1.1)
```

[image]

First, I'm surprised that on a normal `log` axis the line segment marked with the red cross is plotted: the point directly above that segment (at `y=0.05`) equals one, the point below at `y=0` is zero and can't be plotted on a `log` axis, then why does matplotlib draw this segment? This way the plot gives the impression that at e.g. `y=0.01`, `x` equals one, which is incorrect.

(*edit*: `semilogy` does discard the marked line segment...)

Second, I was trying to solve this problem by using a `symlog` axis (right panel), setting a linear region using `linthresy`, but that doesn't seem to work (in this case). Shouldn't this create something like an evenly spaced y-axis with labels at `y = { 0, 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0 }`?

Comment: you can't plot 0 on a logarithmic scale, it would result in `10^-infinity`.

Comment: I know - that's why I was expecting matplotlib to discard the line segment that I marked, and was trying to plot this using a `symlog` axis

Comment: I think you found a bug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem until I realized that the keyword is `linthreshy` rather than `linthresy`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

pl.close('all')

z = np.linspace(0,1,20)
x = np.ones_like(z)
x[0] = 0

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(121)
pl.plot(x, z, '-x')
pl.yscale('symlog', linthresy=1e-2)
pl.xlim(-0.1,1.1)

pl.subplot(122)
pl.plot(x, z, '-x')
pl.yscale('symlog', linthreshy=1e-2)
pl.xlim(-0.1,1.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, strange that Python doesn't complain about a misspelled argument, but I'm glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As an update, since Matplotlib version 3.3, the parameters `linthreshx`/`linthreshy` have been replaced with `linthresh`.